# Matchings in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $M$ and $N$ be matchings in a graph $G$ with $|M| > |N|$. Prove their exist matchings $M'$ and $N'$ in $G$ such that $|M'| = |M| - 1$ and $|N'| = |N| + 1$, and $M'∪ N' = M ∪ N$ and $M'∩ N' = M∩ N$.

Let $M$ and $N$ be nonempty matchings with $|M| > |N|$. It's extremely trivial that choosing $M'=N$ and $N'=M$, so obviously we are looking for two different matchings completely. Consider two cases: $M$ is not maximal, and $M$ is maximal. Notice $N$ is not maximal in either case.

1. $M$ is not maximal.  Then there exists a (shortest?) $M$-augmented path in $G$, call it $P$. Choose $N'=E(P)-M$, the edges in the augmented path, but not in the matching. Since this $M$-augmented path is the shortest such one, $|N'| = |M|$ There also exists an $N$-augmented path, say $Q$, and we can choose $M' = E(Q) - N$...I'm not sure if this is going to work out..
2. $M$ is maximal, I'm not sure how to find the $M'$, but I can intuitively understand that it exists. It's like you choose the "opposite" of it.

Am I way off base here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not off base by much, but you are going in a wrong direction.

**Hint:**

- How many (at most) vertices in $M$ can be covered by $N$?
- Take any uncovered vertex, how can you modify $N$ so that it covers that vertex in addition to all it covers now?

I hope it helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Well, M is a set of edges, not vertices. Could you clarify? I'm not sure if you refer to the vertices that are in the subgraph induced by M, or if you actually meant to say edges.

Comment: If you are talking about vertices, then the subgraph induced by $N$ can cover at most $2|N|$ of the vertices in $M$. There would be two vertices left over, uncovered. To cover them, I would have to add the missing edge to $N$; i.e., take $M ∪ N$...which would be pointless...

Comment: I'm talking about vertices, not edges. You would have to add an edge of $M$, and then perhaps remove an edge of $N$, and because of it add another edge of $M$, and so on...

Comment: Yes, $N$ could have at most 1 fewer edge than $M$, in which case $N$ could cover $2|N|$ vertices in $M$, and you'd have to add that missing edge that's in $M$. But thinking about a square...you could choose M to be the side edges, and $N$ to be the top edge. Then, all about 2 vertices in $M$ are covered by $N$, but we'd have to add *the remaining edge in the square*. Adding anything from $M$ to $N$ no longer makes it a matching, so you'd have to take away and add again....I'm not really seeing it....

Comment: Perhaps could you clarify what you meant by "You are not off base by much, but you are going in a wrong direction"? Because I don't see what you suggested as a hint making any reference to where I was going.

Comment: Take a XOR of $M$ and $N$, it will be a collection of disjoint cycles and paths. Each such path ends at a vertex covered by exactly one of $M$ and $N$, but $M$ has at least two more vertices uncovered by $N$ than $N$ by $M$. Hence there is a path which starts and ends with an edge of $M$. Take that path $P$ and set $N'=N\oplus P$, $M' = M\oplus P$.

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say "covered", do you mean "incident to"? Because $M$ and $N$ are matchings (which are just collections of edges--no vertices).

Comment: With everything I wrote you should be able to verify by yourself whether it works with such an interpretation (yes, I do mean "incident to", see [edge cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover) and [vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover)).

Comment: I appreciate your help. We just learned these topics recently and I get confused with the exact terminology. If I don't get it then I confuse it for something else (e.g., I might start mistaking $M$ for a set of vertices now!). I wrote it all out and it seemed t make sense except for a couple of minor issues which I will look over after I've had a nap.

Comment: Sure, do your work and then if you were to have more questions I will be glad to answer them (probably not today though, it's quite late here).